# Android How to determine whether the ClientConnectionManager opened a new connection or used existing one?

Tags: android

We created a class deriving from `DefaultHttpClient` and use a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy`. Now I'd like to know during runtime whether the `ClientConnectionManager` reused a connection or created a new one (for instance because the connection with the server timed out).

How can I tell?

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient
{
    // some code setting constants

        public MyHttpClient()
        {
            super();

            // some code setting http connection params


            setKeepAliveStrategy(new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy()
            {
                @Override
                public long getKeepAliveDuration(final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context)
                {
                    return KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT * MS_PER_SECOND;
                }
            });

        }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager()
    {

        // some code registering HTTP and HTTPS 

        return new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }       

    // some code for the socketfactory
}

// At some other class:

public class SomeClass
{
   private static final HttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = new MyHttpClient();

   public void someMethod()
   {
    /* some code */

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(some url);
    HttpResponse getResponse = HTTP_CLIENT.execute(get);

    /* more code */
   }
}
```

When we call `HTTP_CLIENT.execute()` how can I see whether a new connection was created by the `ClientConnectionManager` or an existing connection was reused?

Comment: iam not geeting wat ur problem is exactly,can u xplian clearly

Comment: It's not a problem, it works, but I'd like to verify things.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out by searching the internet and measuring the time it takes to get a lot of data using a https conenction:

1. The clientConnectionManager will by default try to reuse the connection, whether you define a keep alive strategy or not. setKeepAlive strategy will give you something to tinker but I could not find much difference in the time it took to get my data.
2. Using setReuseStrategy you can make sure a new connection is made forevery datafetch and then I saw that the time for getting a lot of data often doubled ! This is because of the overhead for setting up an https connection.